# Java Virtual Field Pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to understand and implement Java Virtual Field Pattern. So far I haven't been able to find many examples or resources on it. This particular [resource](https://github.com/esfand/printit/blob/master/java-virtual-field-pattern.md) explains it but not clearly on how it should be implemented. Would someone be able to better explain it or use a new example?

Comment: I have never heard the term "virtual field" before. It looks like the author is just trying to reinvent the calculated/synthetic *property*.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think so. Looks like it's using default methods to simulate property mixins.

Comment: @shmosel Perhaps. I'd just say "use Groovy". ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain the pattern using an example similar to the one from the linked [mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-July/005171.html) in the linked resource.

Supposed there is a `Peeker` interface like this:

```
interface Peeker<T> {
    T peek();
    T take();
}
```

You want to your class to implement it but you don't want to implement all method yourself - you just want to delegate all method calls to an existing implementation of `Peeker`. So you might write your class like this:

```
class Foo implements Peeker<T>{

    private Peeker<T> peeker = new PeekerImpl();

    public T peek() {
        return peeker.peek();
    }

    public T take() {
        return peeker.take();
    }
}
```

To avoid this boilerplate (especially if you have many other classes that use `Peeker` in a similar way) you can use the mentioned pattern. You extend the `Peeker` interface and use default methods to delegate all calls:

```
interface PeekerView<T> extends Peeker<T> {

    Peeker<T> getPeeker();

    default T peek() {
        return getPeeker().peek();
    }
    default T take() {
        return getPeeker().take();
    }
}
```

Now the interface does all delegation automatically. Your class only has to implement the `PeekerView` interface and implement only the `getPeeker` method:

```
class Foo implements PeekerView<T>{

    private Peeker<T> peeker = new PeekerImpl();

    public Peeker<T> getPeeker() {
        return peeker;
    }

}
```

To implement the Pattern you basically just move all delegate calls to the `PeekerView` interface's default methods.

---

By the way I think "virtual field pattern", as Brian Goetz calls it, is not the best name for this. I guess it makes sense if you only look at the interfaces - the getter acts like a virtual field in this case. If you look at the whole thing though, including the implementing class, it is effectively like some kind of *mixin* (as it is also called in the other [linked article](https://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/java-8-now-you-have-mixins/)). I would call it *Mixin Pattern* instead, because I've seen it referred to by that name more often.

Comment: I've implemented the pattern as an annotation processor if you're interested. https://github.com/reegnz/virtual-field-processor
I am even contemplating publishing it to maven central.